# Import Safari data into Safari Technology Preview

Tags: safari, macos

I have installed the [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/) and whilst everything works fine, there is a lot of data which is missing and not been migrated.

Bookmarks, Reading List and AutoFill have been transferred automatically through iCloud, and eventually History through iCloud too, but I would like to also transfer the following data:

- Cookies
- Preferences
- Extensions (specifically the extension preferences — I can reinstall the actual extensions)

How can I export my Safari browser data into the Safari Technology Preview?

Comment: Doesn't history sync if you enable iCloud sync of safari data?

Comment: @bmike I would have thought so, but it does not appear to.

Comment: It's a 1.0 :-) Since that is documented to work, perhaps it's a bug they haven't fixed yet.

Comment: @bmike History synced successfully eventually, but still nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

Coping ~/Library/Safari to ~/Library/SafariTechnologyPreview works for me.

On the command line, run:

```
cp -R ~/Library/Safari ~/Library/SafariTechnologyPreview
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The only content in the Safari Technology Preview is what has been transferred from iCloud and this doesn't change that.

Comment: Didn't work for me either.